# Defining custom Keys

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
IDbb5d7b0afbe40651f54120e31eb7fdd6  SI|us_us-800148_Rachel%20Maddow|http://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow-show TI1393717980    FC10    **UAMozilla/5.0** (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11
```

I am a beginner in `Hadoop` `MapReduce` looking for some guidance

Above is 1 sample record. I have a flat file that contains 10,000 similar records. If I want to read only the `UAMozilla` from the following line and count its occurrence in the file. How can I achieve this using `MapReduce` in Java. Please help as I have been looking to resolve this for days with no luck !!!

Sincere thanks !

Comment: Please post what you have tried or looked into as well as any error message or snag that you have run into. This is so that we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `WordCount` program that comes with the hadoop examples. Instead of emitting entire words as keys emit only UAMozilla/5.0,1 from your map.

To extract UAMozilla/5.0 alone from the log line, simply use a regex.